# jQuery CSS appending with no effect

Tags: jquery, css, append

```
$('body').append('<style type="text/css"> body {background:red;} </style>');
```

This doesn't make the background red. Is there away outside the .css() function to do this?
I get css, html and jQuery javascript seperatly through an ajax request so how do I append it the best way?

---

Ok I was trying to simplify the problem but this actually works.. so heres the whole code

```
edit : function(page) {
    $.ajax({ 
        data    : {
            'edit' : page
        },
        success : function(i){
            var html = jQuery.parseJSON(i);

            $('#editPageListContainer, #editPreview').remove();

            var script      = document.createElement('script');
            script.type     = 'text/javascript';
            script.text     = html.js;

            document.body.appendChild(script);

            $('body').append('<style type="text.css">' + html.css + '</style>' + html.php);
        }
    }); 
}
```

****OMG... 
a typo "text.css" in the style type... 
love this font it's so clear to see, love you guys anyway!****

Comment: Seems to work to me: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ2kK/2/

Comment: For future reference, always post the actual problematic code, not code "something like" it. Or, at least make sure your reduced code has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('body').css('background', 'red');
```

Comment: What's reason not to use this ?

Comment: this should not be issue, using after loading ajax response.

Comment: i said OUTSIDE the .css() function.. i have a whole block of css i need to add

Comment: You can use {'attribute':'value', 'attribute':'value', 'attribute':'value'} in CSS function too.

Answer (score 1):

Add your CSS Code to the head tag, that works for me ;o)

```
$("head").append("<style> body {background:red;}</style>");
```

For your AJAX Request it looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url", 
  async:false, 
  success: function(css) {
     $("head").append("<style>"+css+"</style>");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach on this is to specify your styling in a stylesheet by specifying a class that you can use in your scripting. So....you have a css file with a class named 'myClass' and you add that class (with the [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method) in your scripting at the moment you want. In my opinion this is the most clean approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').attr('style', 'background:red');
```